# Как сервисы статистики ведут учет пользователей?

Tags: статистика, яндекс-метрика, аналитика

Интересует, как сервисы статистики (тот же liveinternet или yandex, google) ведут учет уникальных пользователей. Если с количеством просмотров все понятно - просто считается каждый запрос. То как проверяется уникальность? С авторизованными пользователями тоже все более менее ясно - считать не более одного раза в сутки одного username.

> Но когда пользователь не авторизован, как сервис статистики узнает
>   один и тот же пользователь просмотрел сайт или два разных?

Comment: Он скармливает пользователю куки (и/или другие, более экзотические виды данных, возвращаемых на сервер при запросе). Соответственно при следующем обращении пользователь пошлет эту куку серверу и тот его узнает. Собственно любая авторизация на любой сайте использует тот же принцип, только требуя логин и пароль и потом выдает на основе них куку. Плюс отдельно могут учитываться ip-адеса, на случай, если клиент куки не возвращает

Comment: @Mike Так куки же - это настройки сайта, как сервис понимает, что это уникальный пользователь? К тому же куки можно легко удалить? Насчет IP-адреса думаю бред, потому что сейчас зачастую у один провайдер выдает один IP-адрес на 1000 компьютеров, плюс еще дома почти в каждой квартире к роутеру подключено по 4 устройства. Если даже выдает внешний IP, то они постоянно меняются

Comment: Куки это не настройки сайта, а некая информация передаваемая в браузер от определенного доменного имени и возвращаемая браузером при обращении на то же доменное имя. Когда браузер лезет что бы получить скажем картинку счетчика с сервера статистики то он посылет ему куки не данного сайта, а куки привязанные к доменному имени самого сервиса статистики. И если вы удалите куки возможно вас посчитают второй раз, а может нет, решат, что хватит уже считать уникальных с вашего IP. И кроме того вам могут дать ETag, а его вы не удалите

Comment: Ну ip в любом случае учитывается для избежания накрутки. в любом случае все что есть при обращении, это куки, ETag, информация о браузере, IP. Больше ничего. Так что лично я бы сделал так: если с данного ip обращений еще не было - уникальный, если были, смотрим куки, если кука/ETag есть, смотрим по ним, если нет и ip уже был сегодня - не считаем за уникального

Comment: Получается с одного и того же компьютера авторизованного и неавторизованного пользователя будут считать за двух разных? И еще правильно ли я понимаю, что с каждым запросом удаляя куки и меняя прокси, я могу сделать накрутку в 1000 посетителей в день?

Comment: ну когда у вас столько прокси вы можете делать все что угодно. включая запоминание с какой кукой вы ходили через кукую проксю и отдачу именно ее. тогда вы уж точно будете уникальным. если вас не засекут еще как нибудь собрав информацию досутпную javascript

Comment: Хорошая коллекция способов опознания пользователей есть в [evercookie](https://github.com/samyk/evercookie).

Comment: @D-side Что-то слышал про evercookie, вроде как вечные неубиваемые куки, но так и не понял как это работает? Эта очень крутая штука, которой пользуются топовые сайты, что тут и прокси не спасет? Или все же это нечто слишком ненативное тормознутое и с огромным количеством недостатков?

Comment: Не слышал ни об одном сайте, который бы ею пользовался. Но в ридми описаны все механизмы, которые используются для отслеживания. Да, некоторые из этих механизмов пробивают прокси.

Comment: @Mike Насчет Etag вы уверены? Что-то толком нет инфы, что с его помощью можно статистику собирать

Comment: Абсолютно уверен, я с помощью него собираю :)

Comment: И кстати еще забыли DNS. Он не дает идентифицировать клиента, но позволяет засечь некоторые виды проксей, включая tor. дело в том, что запрос DNS придет на хост от вашего провайдера, если ваша машина использовала его dns-сервера. подсовываешь на сайте получение любого контента по уникальному имени и смотришь откуда запрос пришел. Если регион провайдера и пользователя не совпадают, значит очень вероятна прокся